# How to hide the bottom tab navigator in subscreens ( TabBarVisible = true is not working)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I am using createBottomNavigator to set the tabBarBottom in my app. I have many screens and subscreens.

For example, I have 5 main screens and for each screen I have subscreens. I need to hide the bottom bar in some of the subscreens. It not working, If I set tabBarVisible: false. Can anyone give an answer for this[image]

Comment: You can make your custom bottom bar component and render it in which file you needs

Comment: I need to show the footer to one or two subscreens. I have got answer by referring another thread.